# How to print total number of file descriptors with index 24

Tags: proc, file-descriptors

How can I print the total number of file descriptors with index 24 for all the running processes on Linux?

I tried

```
$ ls /proc/*/fd 2> errors.txt > stdout.txt | grep "^24" stdout.txt | wc -l
```

This solution returns 0 every time.

I mention that my task asks me to write a one liner in order to solve it.

Comment: If you can help me without creating those files: errors.txt and stdout.txt, would be perfect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
find /proc/[0-9]*/fd/ -name 24 2> /dev/null | wc -l
```

Or, if you insist on using `ls` (this should be one of the [few examples](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) where it is safe to do so):

```
ls /proc/[0-9]*/fd 2>/dev/null | grep -c '^24$'
```

Your first attempt failed because you were redirecting the output to a file (`> output.txt`) which means that the `grep` would never match since it had no output to match against. You could either use pipes (`|`) as I did above or, use a `;` or `&` to separate the commands:

```
ls /proc/[0-9]*/fd 2> errors.txt > stdout.txt; grep "^24" stdout.txt | wc -l
```

Answer (score 4):

There's not point calling `ls` or `find` here. That's the shell doing the job by expanding the glob.

Just:

```
set -- /proc/[0-9]*/fd/24 && echo "$#"
```

A caveat with that is that, except with `zsh`, if you get `1`, you don't know if it's because there's one or if the pattern did not match.

With `bash`, you can do

```
shopt -s nullglob
fds=(/proc/[0-9]*/fd/24)
echo "${#fds[@]}"
```

Another option, which would be more portable would be to use `lsof`:

```
lsof -td24 | wc -l
```

Comment: Use `setopt nullglob` in `zsh` the get 0 when there are no matches.

Comment: @pts, or `set -- /proc/[0-9]*/fd/24(N)` which is better than turning on a global setting.